# Error Bar plots, how to rid of error bar central line when using plotmarks

Tags: plotting, graphics

here is my code:

```
Needs["ErrorBarPlots`"]
hw = 0.02; (*This is the scale of the Error bars horisonatl line in \
regards to the scale of the error*)
plotdata17 = ErrorListPlot[{{{0.1, 0.3}, ErrorBar[0.4]}, {{0.3, 0.5}, 
    ErrorBar[0.1]}, {{0.4, 0.1}, ErrorBar[0.3]}, {{0.6, 0.3}, 
    ErrorBar[0.3]}},

  ErrorBarFunction -> 
   Function[{coords, 
     errs}, {(*the vertical line:*){AbsoluteThickness[3], 
      Line[{coords - {0, errs[[2, 1]]}, 
        coords + {0, 
          errs[[2, 1]]}}]},(*horizontal tick 1:*){AbsoluteThickness[
       3], Line[{coords - {hw, -errs[[2, 1]]}, 
        coords + {hw, 
          errs[[2, 1]]}}]},(*horizontal tick 2:*){AbsoluteThickness[
       3], Line[{coords - {hw, errs[[2, 1]]}, 
        coords + {hw, -errs[[2, 1]]}}]}}],

  AxesOrigin -> {0.0, 0.0},
  PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {-1.1, 1.1}},
  AspectRatio -> 0.40,
  PlotMarkers -> {{\[EmptyCircle], 30}},
  Joined -> True,

  PlotStyle -> {{AbsoluteThickness[3], 
     RGBColor[0.49, 0.76, 1]}, {AbsoluteThickness[3], 
     RGBColor[0, 0.435, 0.952]}, {AbsoluteThickness[3], 
     RGBColor[0, 0.345, 0.705]}, {AbsoluteThickness[3], 
     RGBColor[0, 0.235, 0.69]}, {AbsoluteThickness[3], 
     RGBColor[0, 0.007, 0.6]}, {AbsoluteThickness[3], 
     RGBColor[0, 0, 0]}},

  ImageSize -> {1000, 1000}, Frame -> True, 
  FrameStyle -> AbsoluteThickness[3], 
  FrameTicksStyle -> 
   Directive[50, FontFamily -> fontused, AbsoluteThickness[3]], 
  FrameTicks -> {{{{-1, "-1.000"}, {0, "0.000"}, {1.000, "1.000"}}, 
     Automatic}, {Automatic, None}}, Axes -> False, 
  PlotMarkers -> None, 
  FrameLabel -> {Style["\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(Z\), \(S\)]\)", 20, 
     FontFamily -> fontused], 
    Style["\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(D\), \(S\)]\)", 20, 
     FontFamily -> fontused]}, 
  LabelStyle -> {30, FontFamily -> fontused}]
```

i want to get rid of the central errorbar line that Mathematica adds by default.
how do i get rid of it (and NOT by removing the plot markers)?

[image]

Comment: If you don't want the vertical line why are you drawing it?  Simply remove `(*the vertical line:*)` part from the `ErrorBarFunction` to get the result that Chris shows in his answer.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
plotdata17 /. Line[{{a_, _}, {a_, _}}] :> {}
```

[image]

Comment: Fair enough :) ... what i meant was: How do I remove the Central horizontal line

Comment: @yoav What central horizontal line?  The main line of the plot?  If so why are you using `Joined -> True`?

Comment: How do i add an Image (screen capture) i will add a picture of what i mean

Comment: OK, I have added the picture (SEE ABOVE in original question post)
of the result of the code. As you can see:
The Joining line - as desired and OK 
The error bar top and bottom horizontal lines - as desired and OK
The Vertical line of the error bar - as desired and OK

there is an added artifact a central horizontal line that i need to get rid of (crossing each plot mark), I hope i made it clearer

Comment: @yoav What version are you using? When I run the code you posted, I do not get the middle lines

Comment: this code is from VER 10.0